# Iterate Multiple DataTables

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `SQL Server` stored procedure that I run two select statements.  I can easily return one select statement and store it in a `DataTable` but how do I use two?

How can I set my variable `countfromfirstselectstatement` equal to the count returned from my first select statement and how can I set my variable `countfromsecondselectstatement` equal to the count returned from the second select.

```
private void ReturnTwoSelectStatements()
{
  DataSet dt112 = new DataSet();
  using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Return2SelectStatements", con))
    {
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(dt112);
        }
    }
  }
  DataTable table1 = dt112.Tables[0];
  DataTable table2 = dt112.Tables[1];

  string countfromFirstSelectStatement = table1.Rows.Count().ToString();
  string countfromSecondSelectStatement = table2.Rows.Count().ToString();

  //I only want to iterate the data from the 1st select statement
  foreach (DataRow row in dt112.Rows)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to Fill a DataSet instead? A DataSet has a Tables collection.

Comment: @Steve - so instead of populating a datatable populate a dataset and iterate the tables?

Comment: Yes or as Luaan answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill a Dataset with both select statements and access it:

```
....
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dataSet);
....

DataTable table1 = dataSet.Tables[0];
DataTable table2 = dataSet.Tables[1];

string countfromFirstSelectStatement = table1.Rows.Count.ToString();
string countfromSecondSelectStatement = table2.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry about that. forgot to add `DataSet.Tables` property. Thanks @Steve

Comment: Using this throws my iteration syntax - what would I need to alter this to foreach (DataRow row in dt112.Rows)

Comment: 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataSet' could be found - I only want to iterate the rows returned from my first Select statement or table1 (in your syntax above)

Comment: Does your code look something like `foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)`? or in your case: `DataTable dt112 = dataSet.Tables[0]; foreach (DataRow row in dt112.Rows)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107962/discussion-between-cyi-and-rashidinman).

Answer (score 2):

You could also directly use the `DbDataReader` (`cmd.ExecuteReader()`), which gives you `NextResult` to advance to the next result set. `DataTable.Load` allows you to load rows from the data reader to the table.

`DbDataAdapter` is really a bit of an overkill for just reading data into a data table. It's designed to allow the whole CRUD-breadth of operation for controls that are abstracted away from the real source of data, which isn't really your case.

Sample:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  dataTable1.Load(reader);

  if (!reader.NextResult()) throw SomethingWhenTheresNoSecondResultSet();

  dataTable2.Load(reader);
}
```